# Error during opening file: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: arraycopy: destination index -4 out of bounds for byte[256]

Tags: sshj

During opening the file in this way:

`RemoteFile remoteFile = sftpClient.open(path)`

I've faced with following error with stacktrace:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: arraycopy: destination index -4 out of bounds for byte[256]
>       at net.schmizz.sshj.common.Buffer.putRawBytes(Buffer.java:271)
>       at net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.ChannelOutputStream$DataBuffer.write(ChannelOutputStream.java:64)
>       at net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.ChannelOutputStream.write(ChannelOutputStream.java:141)
>       at net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.ChannelOutputStream.write(ChannelOutputStream.java:131)
>       at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPEngine.transmit(SFTPEngine.java:292)
>       at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPEngine.request(SFTPEngine.java:130)
>       at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPEngine.doRequest(SFTPEngine.java:136)
>       at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPEngine.open(SFTPEngine.java:141)
>       at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient.open(SFTPClient.java:68)
>       at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient.open(SFTPClient.java:73)
>       at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient.open(SFTPClient.java:78)
>       at com.echovox.paidle.common.util.SftpUtil.getFileDataListFromZip(SftpUtil.java:86)
>       at com.echovox.paidle.common.util.SftpUtil.lambda$getFileDataWithRetry$1(SftpUtil.java:139)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

I found 3 implementation of `open` method:

`public RemoteFile open(String filename)`

`public RemoteFile open(String filename, Set<OpenMode> mode)`

`public RemoteFile open(String filename, Set<OpenMode> mode, FileAttributes attrs)`

Is it possible to use somehow `Set<OpenMode> mode` and/or `FileAttributes attrs` to avoid this issue?

Comment: Just making sure, you are trying to write file to remote server? Does the file exist there or are you creating a new one?

You could try with this one:
`sftpClient.open(path, EnumSet.of(OpenMode.WRITE, OpenMode.READ, OpenMode.CREAT, OpenMode.TRUNC));` If you are appending, try with `EnumSet.of(OpenMode.WRITE, OpenMode.READ, OpenMode.APPEND))`

Comment: I have tried to do like you said but it does not work anyway